# Using jQuery object of elements and :contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find if a link containing the word 'gathered'.

I am aware of the logic to get it but I am struggling to have a jQuery sintax for the selector:

```
if (index === 3) {

    var $link = $('#rest').find('.trigger');

    var $currentLinkPage = $link.eq(index - 1);

    $($currentLinkPage + ":contains('gathered')").......

}
```

The console returns: 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:contains('gathered')'

Is there a way of using `:contains` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$currentLinkPage.filter(':contains("gathered")')
```

- Your `$currentLinkPage` is a jQuery object of `.trigger` elements
- You only need to filter for the ones that contain the text you seek

Note: `eq` may not be what you need, update your question for what you're trying to get at

Comment: I am going to try. Thank you:)

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, its a best practice to prefix jQuery variables with `$` so that you know it's a jQuery object (easier to keep track).  In this case `currentLinkPage` should be called `$currentPageLink`

Comment: @viery365 you don't need to edit the question, it's to note going forward (update your code, not the question).  It's generally good SO practice to not alter the major content of the question unless your question was malformed or missing information.  This is important so that years from now, the answers still make sense.  That said, good luck, may your problems be few and your answers come swift.

Comment: Thank you:) I edited the question anyway. My code follows your recommendation (of using a `$` prefixing variables with jQuery objects) but I had to make many changes when copying-paste it here, to make it understandable and I forgot to prefixing the variable in the question. But yes, maybe it would be better to not edit for that the answer still makes sense in the future:)